# Is there a way to add a cancel button to `QLPreviewController`

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I want to use `QLPreviewController` to edit images in my app. Just using vanilla code to present this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let quickLookViewController = QLPreviewController()
    quickLookViewController.dataSource = self
    quickLookViewController.delegate = self
    tappedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FileCell
    quickLookViewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = indexPath.row
    present(quickLookViewController, animated: true)
}
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to add cancel button functionality to the `QLPreviewController`? I've heard of putting it in a navigation controller and then adding buttons to the bar, but I don't want to do this since it's hacky and causes strange transition animation issues.

It seems strange there isn't a cancel button by default since if you annotate a photo form within the iOS photos app it provides both a "Done" and a "Cancel" button.

Comment: embed it in a navigationcontroller add a cancel button on that bar

Comment: This is a hacky workaround. Note also that if you present a `QLPreviewController` that's embedded in a navigation controller the buttons will change as it presents. eg the right bar button will initially be a share button and then turn into the annotate button.

Comment: @Kex You can subclass `QLPreviewController` and `override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`. You can present an alert controller and ask if the user would like to save or discard changes.

Comment: @LeoDabus does't `QLPreviewController` always save by default when dismissed though?

Comment: No you can implement your own `didSaveEditedCopyOf` method. It is been a while when I did it but I had the option to discard changes, save a copy or overwrite the file. Make sure to use editingModeFor `createCopy`